# What is post sexualism, and is there a non confessional imperative?

Tags: foucault, sexuality

Who knows their sexuality, rather than their preferred behaviours?

But surely Foucault isn't denying that we like, or prefer, some things or people. So in what way is [post-seuality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postsexualism_(Michel_Foucault)) relevant?

Specifically:

- Does it amount to the rejection of an identity to behaviour?
- In what way can doing so still be "confessional"?

Comment: It's part of my identity narrative that Foucalt is wrong. Also, I often wonder why there are not more solipsists.

Comment: @puppetsock Surely there is only one.

Answer (score 1):

- Identity is changing, fluid, *performed* rather than in-built. This means that our behaviour (which is a series of different events rather than a one-off phenomenon) shapes our identity. Therefore the question 'what is your identity' is inherently wrong/misleading, because it presupposes stability that simply does not exist.
- It is confessional in a sense that power is purposefully used to create discourses in order to regulate individual's sexual behaviour/preferences. That way it successfully attempts to inform public's perception over what is dominant/acceptable and what is deviant. Priests, teachers and psychologists/doctors reinforce this idea of 'putting labels' on activities/preferences that were previously seen as normal and not deserving a separate name to distinguish them from something different (e.g. homosexuality now seen as opposed to heterosexuality).